# NextJS server side development behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm writing some server-side API's in NextJS.  These APIs fetch data from the Internet - and their fetches are being blocked as my development machine is behind a corporate proxy (the target environment is in the cloud - the problem is on my development machine on a corporate network).

How do I route my NextJS app's outbound fetches through a corporate proxy without changing the underlying code base?

--

Development machine is Mac OS X.  NextJS version is 13.4.19.  The package manager is yarn ("classic") - v1.22.19.

Have tried installing global-agent via yarn, setting GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY & GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTPS_PROXY in my project's .env file - then invoking node like this:

`$ node -r global-agent/bootstrap -r cross-fetch/polyfill —no-experimental-fetch node_modules/next/dist/bin/next dev`

In both cases server-side fetches still fail due to being blocked by the firewall.

I've tried setting proxy environment variables in the OS (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY).  Python's requests package respects these environment variables and it is able to successfully connect to the API endpoints that I'm trying to access from within my NextJS app.

Have also tried configuring a proxy from within Yarn as described [here](https://documentation.coremedia.com/cmcc-10/current/webhelp/frontend-en/content/InstallationProxy.html) - but as expected, this routes the yarn package manager's requests through the proxy, not those of my app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Regarding your "PS":  you're good.  I'd actually remove the entire PS about "this is my first post...".  Just take any feedback that comes without making a disclaimer.  People will let you know if something needs changing, it goes without saying.  Feedback on the quality of the question itself will be provided as comments as people deem necessary without needing to solicit it, believe me! ;)

Comment: @Wyck done - thanks mate

Comment: I don't believe Next.js has any sort of built-in HTTP client. What are you using to make the requests?

Comment: @Phil Just fetch.  Although fairly flexible on what I use.  May not be strictly a NextJS question - but a question about the stack of Next and NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Axios to fetch your data.
Axios has in built features useful to help with proxy issues.

Set your proxys like:

Window terminal

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<Proxy_host>:<port>  
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://<Proxy_host>:<port>
```

Linux terminal

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<Proxy_host>:<port>  
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://<Proxy_host>:<port>
```

Alternatively change your code:
No Auth:

```
axios.get('https://httpbin.org/ip',
    {
        proxy: {
            protocol: 'http',
            host: '149.129.239.170',
            port: 8080,
        },

        responseType: 'json',
    }
)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Auth:

```
axios.get('https://httpbin.org/ip',
    {
        proxy: {
            protocol: 'http',
            host: 'proxy_host',
            port: portNumber,
            auth: {
                username: '',
                password: ''

            },
        },

    }
)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      }).catch(err => console.error(err))
```